# Configure Sublime Text on OS X to show full directory path in title bar

Tags: sublimetext

On Linux, Sublime Text shows the full path of my currently open file in the title bar by default, but on OS X, it only shows the name of the file.

How can I configure Sublime on OS X to show the full path to the currently open file in the title bar?

Comment: For those who are looking for file path in the **status bar**, there is a plugin [`Statusbar Path`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Statusbar%20Path)

Answer (score 251):

With Sublime Text 3, all that's necessary is to [edit your Sublime user preferences](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html) (`Preferences -> Settings - User`) to include:

```
{
  // ... other settings
  "show_full_path": true
}
```

Then, restart sublime so the new settings are loaded.

This will override the OS X-specific default value for this option, which is `false`.

Comment: Is there a way to customize the path? I don't really want the full path, or just the name of the file, but rather the path based on the folder I oppened. `my-app/app/templates/something.hbs` - or `my-app - templates/something.hbs`

Comment: Then, do one restart sublime.

Comment: For newbies and distracted users (I am the latter), in Sublime Text 3 Preferences > Settings opens a vertically splitted window. You have to edit Preferences.sublime-settings on the right pane, adding a colon and the relevant setting.

Comment: @sheriffderek  `"show_full_path": true, "show_rel_path": true,` (on separate lines)

Comment: @TomHundt - excellent! haha. Apparently, I still wanted to know, and it's super helpful in 2023!! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Every little bit helps!
Parathentically, on my Mac I don't need to restart. `Cmd+P` showed up two window panes: I assumed that are global preference (longer file) and user preference (shorter file). I just added the above code line to the User preference, saved file and voila!

Comment: Rightly pointed out by @ChienNguyen, we dont have to restart the Sublime.

Answer (score 18):

Should be the same for Sublime Text 2/3
(Tested on OSX Yosemite)

1. While in sublime go to your "Sublime Text 2/3" menu and move down to "Preferences ->"  then go down to "Settings - User" this will open your user settings in Sublime
2. If you have never added any user setting it should just contain some comments.  If so you can just paste in the following:

***One setting***

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings", and  
// are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.  
{  
"show_full_path": true  
}
```

***Two settings***
( one setting per line and separated by a , )

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings", and  
// are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.  
{   
"show_full_path": true, 
"save_on_focus_lost": true  
}
```

3. Now save this settings file.
4. Now you should be able to see the full path in the title bar.

(NOTE: for me I didn't need to restart Sublime see the path in the title bar, but I think I had to when I was using the Windows version of the program)

FYI in Sublime's full screen mode/distraction free mode, you need to move your pointer to the top of the screen to see the title bar.

I usually just run Sublime where I have manually sized my window to be the full size of the screen so I can always see the title bar.

**Just for clarification when you read:**

```
//Show the full path to files in the title bar.  
// On OS X, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings, so  
// you'll need to place this line in your user settings to override it."
```

It was trying to tell you to modify the Sublime Text User Settings not any OSX system settings.

Comment: how can I confiugre so that insteas of showing the full path from `~/Users/username...`  it will show only from the current directory that i am working on. For example instead of `/Users/username/Desktop/Main/child/project-frontend/src/app/menu.js` it  will only show `project-frontend/src/app/menu.js`

Comment: thumbs up for the completeness

Comment: What does `save_on_focus_lost` do?

Answer (score 6):

In Sublime Text 3 for Mac OS X:

1) Add `"show_full_path": true` to your `Sublime Text / Preferences / Settings - User` file. Add this line even though it already appears as `true` in the default prefs. Terminate the line with a comma (`,`) if you include it among other prefs. Save your changes.

2) Quit and relaunch Sublime.

Unlike other user prefs, you won't see this change until you relaunch the app.

Comment: this may have been true when this answer was posted, but I just tried it in sublime text 3 (build 3114) and it worked without having to restart sublime.